# HAML with Backbone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js

I'm using Rails 3.1 and Backbone with the backbone-rails gem. The views are `jst.ejs`

Is there any way I can use HAML in the views? Are those views precompiled in production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently using this gem: https://github.com/infbio/haml_assets and it's working out okay.

Comment: haml_assets is not working very well. I would recommend [haml_coffee_assets](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets) for using [haml-coffee](https://github.com/9elements/haml-coffee) (see answer by @Netzpirat)

Answer (score 12):

You can use [haml_coffee_assets](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets) for using [haml-coffee](https://github.com/9elements/haml-coffee) templates in the Rails 3.1 asset pipeline. Haml-Coffee is a full HAML implementation in CoffeeScript and with haml_coffee_assets the templates gets compiled in the backend and gets converted in a pure JavaScript template, so no need for CoffeeScript during rendering on the client.

Comment: Awesome, I've tried a few other haml/js libraries, but haml_coffee_assets is definitely the winner

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is what you're looking for.
https://github.com/uglyog/clientside-haml-js

To render Haml on the clientside using backbone (and a jQuery selector):

Put haml.compileHAML(template) in your render() function ala:

```
render: function(){
  var fn = haml.compileHaml(template);
  $(this.el).html(fn({});
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JST, but I do the same thing with HAML and jQuery templates: 
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/06/22/rendering-a-rails-partial-as-a-jquery-template/

Answer (score 0):

In description of this gem https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails said that you can use HAML, but I don't try it.